# parameter value separated with pipe not pass completely to action method from @Url.action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am passing string value which is separated with pipe to action method using jquery.load like below:

```
var filterText = "Programming|Web Apps";
var url = '@Url.Action("LoadSelectedFilterItem", "Article", new { filterData= "filterdata"})';
        url = url.replace('filterdata', filterText);
        $('#dvfilterNavItem').load(url);
```

But when i checked below action method where i passed string parameter there it shows like below:

```
public ActionResult LoadSelectedFilterItem(string filterData)
{
    return Json(true);
}
```

When i debug above code then found like this string parameter contains value like this: "Programming|Web"

Here second value which contains middle space gets truncated.

Comment: Try with `url = url.replace('filterdata', encodeURI(filterText));` or `url = url.replace('filterdata', escape(filterText));`

Comment: @freedomn-m, Thank you, Yes after using encodeURI it is working as expected.